# numpy error in Python-3.6

Tags: python-3.6

I am getting this error while trying to install numpy in Python-3.6.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: Same problem with Python 3.6. I just solved the problem by uninstalling pillow (4.1.0) and then installing an older version of pillow (4.0.0) (pip install Pillow==4.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Update Python to 3.6.1 and see if it helps. This might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9272#issuecomment-309828225) where extensions built with Python 3.6.1 won't work on 3.6.0